# How to make a cut on a circular object with a square object?

Tags: modeling, objects, 3d-view

I am trying to make a cut into a circular object with a cross shaped object. However, every time I attempt to use a boolean modifier + apply it, the cut on the circular object is not made, it disappears. See images. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am very new to modelling.

Before:  [image]

After:

[image]

Comment: It would be a lot easier for someone to help you if you were to upload your .blend file, or at least the part of it with the objects shown in your first image to: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Try the Boolean Fast mode instead of the Exact mode, if it still doesn't work, as Curious says, please share your file

Comment: It's definitely possible to cut out the cross shape from the circular object. Either your boolean modifier settings are wrong or your geometries are not clean/manifold. As the others said, simplest would be to share your file.